# IaC: How to wait for private endpoint DNS propagation?

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, infrastructure-as-code

I have a bicep template that creates an Azure SQL database with a private endpoint. My next step is to use Powershell to run a script against this database using the private endpoint.

I get an error indicating the script can't connect to the database. If I run the script a few minutes later, it will work.

I think this is because of the time needed for DNS propagation.

How can I wait for DNS propagation to complete?
Should I poll with NSLookup, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76904999/19785512) which I worked on for the similar issue.

To specify a delay before connecting to the database or if you want to wait for DNS propagation to complete or pause the script for a specified amount of time, use the [`Start-Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep?view=powershell-7.3) command. You can alter the sleep duration based on your DNS propagation time experiences. Once it's set, try executing the script from the above SO link to make it work as usual.

You can use the below loop to verify if the `DNS` name is resolved to the right IP address and quit the loop if it is.

```
while ((Resolve-DnsName  -Name  $dnsName).IPAddress -ne  $ipAddress) 
{
 Write-Host  "Waiting..." 
 Start-Sleep  -Seconds  10 
 }
```

Comment: I don't know what the IP address is going to be.
What value should $ipAddress have?

Comment: You need to give SQL server IP address in place of it. @DonChambers

Comment: Giving SQL server IP address worked for you! @DonChambers