# How do I use an azure private endpoint from a script called by a bicep?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-network, azure-bicep

I have a bicep that creates an Azure SQL with a private endpoint. Then I use this resource Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2020-10-01, to run a PowerShell script that connects to Azure Sql.

It fails because it is trying to use the public endpoint. How do I force this to use the private endpoint?

I get this error:
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s):

> "Reason: An instance-specific error occurred while establishing a
> connection to SQL Server. Connection was denied since Deny Public
> Network Access is set to Yes
> (https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-settings#deny-public-network-access).
> To connect to this server, use the Private Endpoint from inside your
> virtual network
> (https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/sql-database/sql-database-private-endpoint-overview#how-to-set-up-private-link-for-azure-sql-database)."

Comment: What is there exactly in the PowerShell deployment script? @Don Chambers

Answer (score 0):

1. Run [`Test-NetConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection?view=windowsserver2022-ps) to return detailed connection information, including the time it takes to establish the connection **Or** you can use the [`Resolve-DnsName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/resolve-dnsname?view=windowsserver2022-ps) Powershell command to query the DNS name server of the private endpoint.
2. Change the `connection string` in your `PowerShell` script to include the private endpoint URL. By referring to [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/create-private-endpoint-bicep?tabs=CLI#review-the-bicep-file), I've created a private endpoint for SQL database, added the below deployment script in `script content` block and was able to deploy it successfully.

```bash
resource runPowerShellInline 'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2020-10-01' = {
....
properties: {
 scriptContent: '''
      $serverName = sqlServerName
      $database = databaseName
      $privateEndpointURL = "sqlServerName.privatelink.database.windows.net"
      $connString = "Server=$privateEndpointURL;Database=databaseName;User Id=sqlAdministratorLogin;Password=sqlAdministratorLoginPassword;"
      $SQLconnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
      $SQLconnection.ConnectionString = $connString
      $SQLconnection.Open()
   '''
  }
}
```

***Deployment:***

```bash
az deployment group create --resource-group "Jahnavi" --template-file script.bicep
```

*Portal View deployment:*

[image]

If still the issue persists, Check the `PowerShell` script is running in the context of the virtual network. If you run the deployment script from an Azure VM on the same virtual network as your Azure SQL Database's private endpoint, it should work as expected.